# Strange CSS code, Brackets and Asterisk

Tags: css, css-selectors, styles

I came across the code below at http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_grid.asp

They don't really explain the part that looks like this `[class*="col-"]` and the style that starts with `*`

Can anyone point me to somewhere that explains this CSS code?

```
<style>
   * {
     box-sizing: border-box;
   }

   [class*="col-"] {
        float: left;
        padding: 15px;
        border: 1px solid red;
   }
   .col-1 {width: 8.33%;}
   .col-2 {width: 16.66%;}
   .col-3 {width: 25%;}
 </style>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Attribute Selector:** (the selector with square braces)

This - `[class*="col-"]` is called as an attribute selector. It is used to select an element based on an attribute and its value. In this case it ***selects all elements whose class contains*** `col-`. So, it would apply the style to `.col-1`, `.col-2`, `.col-3` etc.

From the [W3C Spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-3/#attribute-selectors): (Section 6.3.2. Substring matching attribute selectors)

> **[att*=val]**
>
> Represents an element with the att attribute whose **value contains at least one instance of the substring "val"**. If "val" is the empty string then the selector does not represent anything.

<sup>(emphasis is mine)</sup>

**Universal Selector:** (the styles which are under `*`)

The `*` selector is called as the universal selector and it is used to ***select and apply given styles to all elements***.

From the [W3C Spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-3/#universal-selector):

> The universal selector, written as a CSS qualified name [CSS3NAMESPACE] with an asterisk (* U+002A) as the local name, represents the qualified name of any element type. It represents any single element in the document tree in any namespace (including those without a namespace) if no default namespace has been specified for selectors. If a default namespace has been specified, see Universal selector and Namespaces below.

---

In your code, there are some styles which are column to all three `col-*` classes whereas the `width` is different. So, the `[class*="col-"]` selects elements with one of those three classes and adds the common styling to them whereas the individual `.col-1`, `.col-2`, .`col-3` selectors apply the `width` specific to each class.

```css
* { /* select and apply these styles to ALL elements */
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

[class*="col-"] { /* select all elements whose class contains col- */
  float: left;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

/* select elements with specific class */
.col-1 {width: 8.33%;}
.col-2 {width: 16.66%;}
.col-3 {width: 25%;}
```

---

It is more like a regex for selector but you should be careful while using them because `[class*="col-"]` will also select an element whose `class='fevicol-is-an-adhesive'` like in the below snippet.

```css
[class*="col-"] {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<h3>Items that will be selected</h3>
<div class='col-1'>Column 1</div>
<div class='col-2'>Column 2</div>
<div class='col-3'>Column 3</div>
<div class='fevicol-is-an-adhesive'>Fevicol is an adhesive</div>

<h3>Items that will not be selected</h3>
<div class='cols-1'>Column 1</div>
<div class='col2'>Column 2</div>
<div class='column-3'>Column 3</div>
<div class='fevicol'>Fevicol is an adhesive</div>
```