# Turning off the background shadow on Angular Material Accordion

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular-material

[In this demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wsppom?file=src%2Fapp%2Fexpansion-overview-example.css), I managed to turn off the background shadow on the Angular Material Accordion using this rule:

```
.mat-expansion-panel:not([class*='mat-elevation-z']) {
  box-shadow: none !important;
  /* box-shadow: 0px 3px 1px -2px rgb(0 0 0 / 20%), 0px 2px 2px 0px rgb(0 0 0 / 14%), 0px 1px 5px 0px rgb(0 0 0 / 12%); */
}
```

I have never seen this type of rule ( `[class*= ...]` ) before.

What does this do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Strange CSS code, Brackets and Asterisk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35622038/strange-css-code-brackets-and-asterisk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an attribute wildcard selector. It looks for any child element under .mat-expansion-panel that has a class that [class*='mat-elevation-z'] element.

Here are some references that help you more to understand about wildcard selector

1. *[CSS3 Attribute Selectors: Substring Matching](http://www.impressivewebs.com/css3-attribute-selectors-substring-matching/)*
2. *[CSS Attribute Selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp#:%7E:text=CSS%20%5Battribute*%3D%22value%22,to%20be%20a%20whole%20word!)*